# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plugins')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am upgrding angular 8 app to 9 , i have installed angular 9 successfuly and it also compiling sucessfully but didnot render in browser.[error

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM7jK.png)

```
//variable.ts
import {insertVariableCommand} from '../commands';
import grapesjs from 'grapesjs';

export default grapesjs.plugins.add('insertVariables', (editor, options) => {
  // proper way to add button into above options bar.
  editor.Panels.addButton('options', {
    id: 'insert',
    className: 'fa fa-subscript',
    context: 'insert-variable',
    command: insertVariableCommand,
    attributes: {
      'title': 'Insert Variable',
      'data-tooltip-pos': 'bottom',
      'id': 'insert-variable-id',
      'opt': options.variables
    },
  });
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "visualivr",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "config": "ts-node ./set-env.ts",
    "start": "npm run config -- --environment=dev && ng serve",
    "dev-build": "npm run config -- --environment=dev && ng build",
    "build": "npm run config -- --environment=prod && ng build --configuration=production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.13",
    "@beyerleinf/ngx-dnd": "8.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "5.3.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~4.0.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "~5.0.5",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.21.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.0.2",
    "@swimlane/ngx-graph": "~6.2.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "3.5.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.119",
    "angular-cc-library": "~1.2.5",
    "angular-crumbs": "^3.0.1",
    "angular-dual-listbox": "~4.7.0",
    "angular2-collapsible": "0.8.0",
    "chart.js": "~2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^3.32.2",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "grapesjs": "^0.17.27",
    "grapesjs-parser-postcss": "^1.0.1",
    "grapesjs-plugin-ckeditor": "0.0.10",
    "grapesjs-preset-webpage": "^0.1.11",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "materialize-css": "~1.0.0",
    "moment-timezone": "~0.5.26",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.5",
    "ng-recaptcha": "6.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "2.4.3",
    "ng2-events": "~4.2.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^8.2.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "2.1.11",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.5.1",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "~3.3.1",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-plaid-link": "1.0.2",
    "ngx-smart-modal": "^7.4.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "8.2.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "8.0.0",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
    "querystring": "^0.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "save": "^2.9.0",
    "tinymce": "~5.0.16",
    "transformation-matrix": "~1.15.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack": "^4.47.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.59",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "dotenv": "~6.2.0",
    "dotenv-utils": "~0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^5.1.1",
    "jasmine-marbles": "~0.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "3.8.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
    "yargs": "~12.0.2"
  }
}
```

i want to upgrade angular 8 to 9 ,I'd greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or solutions that can help me understand and fix this error. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Does that grapesjs package have a default export? Nvm, [it does](https://github.com/GrapesJS/grapesjs/blob/2300c23ad447f32b435322cbb694133fea4b53d5/src/index.ts#L139).

Comment: It looks like you're a few minor versions behind latest though, did you try upgrading that package?

Answer (score 1):

Run `ng update` to check if everything is updated properly, Or run `npm outdated` i believe your problem have something to do with one of your packages

Also you are using Angular 9 which is very old version, Latest stable version is 16

Comment: i have checked my packges with npm outdated everthing looks fine

Comment: Perhaps consider updating your project to an updated version of Angular, Let me know if you need help with that